# Mock Beans from Spring Context

Tags: spring, unit-testing, junit, spring-boot

I want create tests working with the Spring Context, with mocked Repository beans. I'm using Spring Boot 1.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT + JUnit + Mockito.

Here is my Test config class:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "myapp", excludeFilters =
@ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE,
        value = {
                OfferRepository.class
        }
)
)
@Configuration
public class TestEdge2EdgeConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public OfferRepository offerRepository() {
       return mock(OfferRepository.class);
    }

}
```

Purpose of this configuration is to exclude OfferRepository from Spring Context and mock it, thank to this I'll be able to write tests who are using Spring Context with mocked database Repository.

Here is my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {TestEdge2EdgeConfiguration.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class OfferActionsControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private OfferRepository offerRepository;

    @Autowired
    private OfferActionsController offerActionsController;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void saveOffer() {
        //given
        BDDMockito.given(offerRepository.save(any(Offer.class))).willReturn(new Offer());
        //when
        ResponseEntity<Offer> save = offerActionsController.save(new Offer());

        //then
        org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(save);
    }
}
```

Test and test configuration directory is:

```
src/test/java/myapp
```

My application configuration and packages containing OfferRepository directory is:

```
src/main/java/myapp/
```

The problem is that Spring Boot is not loading my configuration from TestEdge2EdgeConfiguration.class and mock for OfferRepository  is never created.

Can any body help me with this, please?

Comment: Did you try with @ContextConfiguration(TestEdge2EdgeConfiguration.class) ?

Comment: SpringApplicationConfiguration is similar to the standard @ContextConfiguration but uses Spring Boot's SpringApplicationContextLoader

Comment: I wasn't aware of ComponentScan$Filter annotation but after having read the docs and, if I understand it correctly, why do you need it in this case ? Does it work without the Filter ?

Comment: I want to exclude Bean OfferRepository from the context, and replace it my mock OfferRepository

Comment: Just guessing, but aren't you then excluding all beans of the type OfferRepository that is the real one and the mocked one ?

Comment: That is interesting hint but how to exclude bean from context and replace it mocked one?

Comment: Here is answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35048472/mocking-beans-in-spring-context-using-spring-boot/35063923#35063923

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should be doing it (Assuming you are writing a test for offerActionsController and injecting offerRepository):

```
@Mock
private OfferRepository offerRepository;

@InjectMocks
private OfferActionsController offerActionsController;

@Before
public void setUp(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

You can write your test method as follows:

```
@Test
public void saveOffer() {
    /* Given */
    Mockito.when(offerRepository.save(Mockito.any(Offer.class))).thenReturn(new Offer());

    //when
    ResponseEntity<Offer> save = offerActionsController.save(new Offer());

    //then
    org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(save);
}
```

Comment: This is ok if I want to write unit tests and You are right, but I want to write integration tests with mocked database so I need the spring context up for my puprouse and mocked Repository beans.

Comment: Create a setter for `offerRepository` in your class and then pass your mocked object to the setter from your test class.

Comment: I have deeper structure there under the hood. Controller -> Service -> Repository. So I need Spring Context up and mock Repository

Answer (score 0):

Use [Spingockito](https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/wiki/Home) to replace the bean with a mock using [@ReplaceWithMock](https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/wiki/springockito-annotations). Don't forget to use `@Autowired` with `@ReplaceWithMock` if you need access to the mocked bean in the test.

Comment: Thank You for advice, I was trying to do this but Spingockito seams not working with SpringBoot. Ehh I whish i could find solution for this, but i think @SpringBootApplication make imposible to mock beans in Spring Context.